# meta name="generator" content="7.3.5.244" meaning?

Tags: html, meta-tags, muse

meta name="generator" content="7.3.5.244" appears in the head of an adobe muse based static site. What does the "7.3.5.244" mean/do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, is a version number. Specifically, it is the version of Muse used to generate the site. Version 7.3 is the current version.

More generally, the HTML specification allows the `content` attribute of a `<meta>` tag to contain *anything* describing the generator. A version number is common, but the name of the product is often included for clarity. For example:

```
<meta name="generator" content="WordPress 2.5.1" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response Cody Gray & isherwood. If I want to add a meta name="description" content="Some Description of the Site Here" can I just place it in the head of a Muse generated sites too?

Comment: @user Yes. You can even remove the `generator` attribute if you want. There's nothing special about a Muse-generated site, it is just an HTML page.

Answer (score 2):

> The value must be a free-form string that identifies one of the
>   software packages used to generate the document.

[HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#standard-metadata-names)